# kdevelop detect concurrent file opens

Tags: editing, kdevelop

My favorite editor, geany, has an option "Disk check timeout", after this timeout it checks if someone else has overwritten the file that I'm editing. This is a simple tool to detect if two people work on the same file (we don't use a version control system). Is there an option or a plugin for kdevelop that does the same thing?

Edit: as Zhigalin said KDevelop does the check automatically but only for local files, I need it for files opened using sftp.

Answer (score 0):

In KDevelop this check is always active, you will get a popup as soon as you focus on that file in the editor.

Edit: if you are speaking of remote files than the reply is no, there is  no such functionality.
So you have 4 options:

1. File a proposal [here](https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=kdevelop) (which probably won't get implemented soon because of few active developers)
2. [Patches are always welcome](https://phabricator.kde.org/dashboard/view/8/)
3. [suggested] Start using a version control system like Git, there are even tools to automatically deploy on server when you make commit on a specific branch.
4. Use AutoFS(FUSE) to mount your server as a local folder.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, yes that is true, however that only works with local files, so it doesn't help me, I edit files via sftp. But I have to edit my question.

Comment: Bummer! Then I suppose I could also use autofs so that kdevelop would think the files are local... Neither are solutions that I was hoping for.

Comment: @soger sadly, there is no such functionality. If you are satisfied please accept my answer.